# why the constructor not called by default

Tags: java, constructor

I've heard my lecturers saying that in Java the constructor is called when actually the main starts. But while I was experimenting with it, I came to know that the constructor is not called automatically. The code goes like this.

```
class Anther {

    static void method1(){
        System.out.println("this is method");
    }

    static void method2(){
        System.out.println("this is second one");
    }

    Anther(){
        System.out.println("Anther class");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("first line");

        method1();
        System.out.println("second line");

        method2();
        System.out.println("end of story");     
    }
}
```

and the output came like this

```
first line
this is method
second line
this is second one
end of story
```

Why it didn't print the 'Anther class'.

Comment: Search google (or bing or whatnot) for "java oop trail": enjoy reading!

Comment: (In any case, consider this counter-question: what is a "static method" in Java?)

Comment: mark one of the answer as accepted @test1990bdvt

Comment: I think the answers have pin pointed the answer!!

Answer (score 5):

You have not created `Anther` object. Constructors are called only at the time of object creation.

`static` resources are accessible without crating object.

Answer (score 4):

> I've heard my lecturers saying that in Java the constructor is called
>   when actually the main starts.

I doubt that your lecturer would have actually said that. If he had, then certainly he might have mistaken somewhere, or you might have misunderstood him

Now, here's the thing: -

> A Constructor is not called until you instantiate your class using `new` operator

So, in the above case, the constructor will be called when you use the following code: -

```
Anther obj = new Anther();
```

in your `main` method.

In the above statement `new` operator creates an object of `Anther`, and invokes the constructor on the newly created instance to initialize its state.

Do clarify this thing with your lecturer.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is called automatically when you create `Instance` of the class.

```
Anther ant = new Anther();
```

Here you are creating instance of the class. At this point the constructor will be called.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Anther a = new Anther();//you shoule create instance;
        System.out.println("first line");

        method1();
        System.out.println("second line");

        method2();
        System.out.println("end of story");     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**-** When ever you create an **Object of an class**, **always its Constructor is called**.

**-** Not only **its** `contructor`, but also its **super-class constructor till the Object Class constructor is called.**

**-** And the **forming** of the `object` **flows from Super class to Sub class.**

**-** And you must called create an `Anther class` **instance** so that **its constructor is called.**

**Eg:**

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        Anther a = new Anther();     // Creation of an object of class Anther

        System.out.println("first line");

        method1();
        System.out.println("second line");

        method2();
        System.out.println("end of story");     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default constructor will be called only when we have instance of the class object.

i,e

```
Anther obj  = new Anther();
```

So ,That's why `default` constructor not called.

`static methods` are class variables they are load in `JVM` before calling the constructor.

`super constructor` is out of scope in this example, it is called because there is base class for this Anther class `[Class A extends Class B]`

Hope this will clear your doubt.

Thanks,
Pavan

Comment: Note that, there is always a `super` class, in absence of any explicit super class. Which is `Object`.